# Fortran: How to make multiple procedures share the same procedure interface

Tags: fortran, fortran2003

I have a code that looks like

```
subroutine sub1(f)
    interface
        function f(x)
            (description of f)
        end function f
    end interface

    (do something with f)
end subroutine sub1

subroutine sub2(f)
    interface
        function f(x)
            (description of f)
        end function f
    end interface

    (do something with f)
end subroutine sub2
```

However, the two subroutines `sub1` and `sub2` both use identical interfaces for the dummy function `f`. How do I make these two procedures share the same interface (e.g. using a module)? Do I have to use procedure pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define such reusable "function types" as `abstract interface`s in modules:

```
module m
    implicit none
    abstract interface
        function der(x,y) result(yDot)
            real, intent(in) :: x, y
            real :: yDot
        end function
    end interface
end module

subroutine integrateEuler(derY,x0,xf,y)
    use m
    real, intent(in) :: x0, xf
    real, intent(inout) :: y
    procedure(der) :: derY
    ! code here
end subroutine

subroutine integrateRKF45(derY,x0,xf,y)
    use m
    real, intent(in) :: x0, xf
    real, intent(inout) :: y
    procedure(der) :: derY
    ! code here
end subroutine
```

Using function *pointers* is not necessary, but you can declare them in the same way: `procedure(der), pointer :: funPtr => myFun`

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. I was trying it without "abstract" and of course it did not work.