# Is it possible to enforce a common interface for several subroutines in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Use case: A particular type of subroutine can be used as an argument to another one. What is the best way to avoid code duplication and ensure that all the subroutines intended for use in this argument are defined in the same consistent way?

Something similar is addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34936204 (i.e., use `abstract interface foo` to declare the common interface and `procedure(foo)` to declare the dummy argument). But this is for reusing the same `interface` block in different subroutines. My main problem is how to ensure that the actual implementation of all the "target" procedures conforms to that interface.

A promising feature was that of `module procedure` in submodules, where the interface declaration is in the parent `module`, and the actual implementation does not need re-declare all the dummy arguments and types. But this does does not allow having different implementations for the same interface (or maybe it does using some combination with the above, but they'd still have to be included in the same module, which is something I'd like to avoid).

dummy example:

```
program main
  ...
  call foo(sub1,x,y)
  call foo(sub2,x,y)
  call foo(sub3,x,y)
  call foo(sub4,x,y)
  call foo(sub5,x,y)
  ...
end program main

subroutine foo(f,a,b)
  ...
  call f(a,b,c,d,e,g,h,i...)
  ...
end subroutine foo
```

All `sub1`...`sub5` subroutines have a common interface, and I'd like to define the long list of dummy arguments only once.

Comment: I do not think if there is a way to do this. Each module procedure would need its own unique explicit interface, even if there is a common abstract interface for all of them. Alternatively, you could use Fortran preprocessor to write one explicit interface in an `include` file and `include` it in the appropriate places in each of the subroutines' modules. Preprocessing directives make codes ugly (and sometimes error-prone), but I personally prefer ugliness to duplication and the inevitable possibility of introducing errors due to duplication.

Comment: Instead of a long list of arguments, you could put everything into a structure and just pass in the same structure all over the place: that is, provided the parameters are the same.  Otherwise it is a case of populate structure, call routine, populate structure, call routine which can look quite ugly.

Comment: @cup That's a possibility, but some of these arguments are large arrays which one wouldn't want to copy around, so the structure should use pointers, so the arrays should be targets, and it becomes messy when they're in common blocks and/or equivalenced (legacy code).

Comment: Just to be clear are you trying to avoid writing more than once the dummy argument list and associated declarations for each of the subroutines?

Comment: @IanBush Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Jellby if your `type` containing these arrays is always `intent(in)` then there's no reason it would be copied around. If you still need pointers, you can also make the `type` a `target` rather than the arrays.

Comment: Dummy derived type arguments have the limitation of removing the possibility of optional arguments. Initialization of the components to null values would not be an alternative either, for example in case of logical optional dummy arguments.